# Extend WiFi range through Wireless Access Point - ethernet connection between 2 routers needed?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, wireless-access-point

I've got a Linksys E4200 connected to my modem. I have a spare Linksys E3000 which I want to use as a range extender. Full bandwidth is required, so putting the E3000 (DD WRT firmware) in Repeater/Repeater Bridge mode is not possible. I need to use a wired connection, as you can see on the diagram.

[image: Diagram]

Is a wired connection between both routers a requirement? I can connect both routers to the modem, but not between each other. I'm not willing to pull a Ethernet line between them. Bare in mind that the modem can also act as a switch/router.

Comment: Those are both simultaneous dual-band APs. If you only had 2.4GHz clients, I suppose you could use the 5GHz radios for a wireless backhaul between the APs. You'd still get full bandwidth of 2.4GHz, just not full bandwidth from both bands simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, you'll have to either accept the reduction in bandwidth or lay a cable to connect the two routers.

Comment: Can't I just configure them as two Access Points without a connection between them?

Comment: Yes but then only the E4200 would provide Internet connectivity. The E3000 would just be an isolated WLAN, i.e. the computers connected to it could talk each other and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely work as long as you disable DHCP on the .2 and plug the Ethernet port from the hub into a LAN port and not the WAN port.

I have a daisy chain set up of several routers (3) and switches (2) and it all functions wonderfully.